# Excel display different than value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In one column, I have values like - "Spring 2012", "Fall 2013", "Spring "2014", "Fall 2015" and so on.

What I wish to have is - Cells with display like "Spring xxxx" should have value one less than what appears.

Like -`"Spring 2012" -> "Spring 2011"
       "Fall 2012"   -> "Fall 2012"
       "Spring 2014" -> "Spring 2013"
       "Fall 2014"   -> "Fall 2014"`

I guess I need to apply conditional formatting rule, but I dont know how to use it for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

light the cells you want to convert and run this small macro:

```
Sub FixYear()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> "" And InStr(1, r.Value, " ") <> 0 Then
            ary = Split(r.Value, " ")
            ary(1) = ary(1) + 1
            r.Value = Join(ary, " ")
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

**EDIT#1 - NON-VBA**

With data in **A1** , in ***B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))&--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999)+1
```

copy as needed

Comment: I appreciate your response. However I am working with php and generating excel sheets for the manager. So is there a solution which does not include macros???

Comment: Thank you. It works good. How can I modify it to work only when data is "Spring xxxx" and leave it as it is when data is "Fall xxxx"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data starting from A1, add this formula in B1:

`=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="Fall",A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))&--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Using a "helper column", assuming your data is in A1, to alter cells that start with "Spring":

```
B1:  =IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,FIND("Spring",A1)),RIGHT(A1,1)-1),A1)
```